# how can I add thumbs up and thumbs down at the end of every conversation in bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to get feedback from the user on every answer given by the chatbot. Is there a way I can show a thumbs-up and a thumbs-down icon at the end of every conversation (as of now they are all FAQs) so that I can capture if the user is satisfied with the answer or not?

Answer (score 2):

I've used the suggested actions feature:

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
      .text(response)
      .suggestedActions(builder.SuggestedActions.create(session, [
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "thumbs-up", ""),
                        builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "thumbs-down", ""),
                       ]));
      session.send(msg);
```