# How to make ac-pushbutton(buttons of hero card) to disappear when it is selected/clicked dynamically in webchat botframework

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chatbot

Is there any way to make the buttons to vanish/disappear once it is clicked?. I am working on chatbot development bot framework v4 SDK (NodeJS) deployed to azure to directline channel in which I require Buttons to be disappear once clicked, So user would not have a scope to opt again from the buttons that appeared before.

I found a reference for disabling the button clicked [Disabling Buttons after being clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201779/disabling-buttons-after-being-clicked/52205333) but I would require buttons to disappear completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I add thumbs up and thumbs down at the end of every conversation in bot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047843/how-can-i-add-thumbs-up-and-thumbs-down-at-the-end-of-every-conversation-in-bot)

Comment: use suggestedActions

Comment: Suggested actions would be available at the bottom of the chat but I would require this fuctionality to work with card action buttons